# Acumatica - FieldUpdate event is not executing (Customer Locations AR303020 screen)

Tags: customization, acumatica

I am working with the Customer Locations **AR303020** screen.
Note: I added a “pencil” button to the right of the Location field on the Sales Orders screen to launch the Customer Locations **AR303020** screen as a popup..

**My Experience level:**
Less than one year.

**Issue:**

The Location Selector does not execute a LocationID_FieldUpdated or a LocationCD_FieldUpdated event (tried both, I only need one of them to work for what I am doing).
When I change the Location Selector value in Debug (at runtime), my breakpoint (see below) is not respected and the code is skipped.

​​​​​​​
**Sample code:**

protected void Location_LocationID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated InvokeBaseHandler)

{
 **Breakpoint** if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)

InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

var row = (Location)e.Row;

row.OverrideAddress = true;      // This code is expected to be executed when the
                                                        
           
row.OverrideContact = true;

}

[Screen capture of Customer Locations AR303020](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OpDL.jpg)

**Acumatica version:**
2021 R1 Build 21.118.0038

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone experienced this issue with this particular screen before?
2. Is there something special (not obvious) about this screen that may be getting in-the-way of
   the execution of the FieldUpdated event?
3. Can you suggest other areas besides this screen, that I should look into?
4. Could this be some odd behavior that is present in this version of Acumatica
   (2021 R1 Build 21.118.0038)?

Thank you in advance for sharing any ideas or insights you may have.

Ken Severud

Answer (score 0):

I think the disconnect is between what events you expect to fire based on UI interaction.  Location_LocationID_FieldUpdated will fire after a change to the field for the row is saved to the database.  In the case of LocationID, which is a key field, I would expect this to happen when creating a new Location.  If you would like an event to fire after you've accessed a Location i.e. "When I change the Location Selector value" then you would want to create a Location_RowSelected() event.  See [here](https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=8f77ddc6-374b-4ad9-be20-a282febf88f8) for event info.